# Generate scaled image from off-screen NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview

I have a sequence of off screen NSViews in a Cocoa application, which are used to compose a PDF for printing. The views are not in an NSWindow, or visible in any way.

I'd like to be able to generate thumbnail images of that view, exactly as the PDF would look, but scaled down to fit a certain pixel size (constrained to a width or height). This needs to be as fast as possible, so I'd like to avoid rendering to PDF, then converting to raster and scaling - I'd like to go direct to the raster.

At the moment I'm doing:

```
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapImageRep = [pageView bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:pageView.bounds];
[pageView cacheDisplayInRect:pageView.bounds toBitmapImageRep:bitmapImageRep];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:bitmapImageRep.size];
[image addRepresentation:bitmapImageRep];
```

This approach is working well, but I can't work out how to apply a scaling to the NSView before rendering the bitmapImageRep. I want to avoid using `scaleUnitSquareToSize`, because as I understand it, that only changes the bounds, not the frame of the NSView.

Any suggestions on the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing, which works perfectly. We draw directly into an `NSBitmapImageRep`, but scale the context explicitly using `CGContextScaleCTM` beforehand. `graphicsContext.graphicsPort` gives you the handle on the `CGContextRef` for the `NSGraphicsContext`.

```
NSView *pageView = [self viewForPageIndex:pageIndex];

float scale = width / pageView.bounds.size.width;
float height = scale * pageView.bounds.size.height;

NSRect targetRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, width, height);
NSBitmapImageRep *bitmapRep;

bitmapRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:nil
                                                    pixelsWide:targetRect.size.width
                                                    pixelsHigh:targetRect.size.height
                                                 bitsPerSample:8
                                               samplesPerPixel:4
                                                      hasAlpha:YES
                                                      isPlanar:NO
                                                colorSpaceName:NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace
                                                  bitmapFormat:0
                                                   bytesPerRow:(4 * targetRect.size.width)
                                                  bitsPerPixel:32];

[NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];

NSGraphicsContext *graphicsContext = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:bitmapRep];
[NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:graphicsContext];
CGContextScaleCTM(graphicsContext.graphicsPort, scale, scale);

[pageView displayRectIgnoringOpacity:pageView.bounds inContext:graphicsContext];

[NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:bitmapRep.size];
[image addRepresentation:bitmapRep];

return image;
```

Comment: I was using `bitmapImageRepForCacheDisplayInRect:` and `cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:` to dynamically generate thumbnails for a notebook app at launch. With > 40 pages (layer-hosted NSViews) with lots of visual content, generating thumbnails was taking close to 90 seconds.This wasn't the case in previous versions of macOS. I replaced this method with @tomtaylor's approach above, using a scale of 1.0 (since I need thumbnails to scale fluidly upwards to full size) and thumbnail generation dropped down to 20 seconds (background), with about half the virtual memory use!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `scaleUnitSquareToSize:` and then passing in a smaller rect in to `bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:` and `cacheDisplayInRect:toBitmapImageRep:`?

So, if you downscale it by a factor of 2, you'd pass a rect to with half with bounds and height.

Comment: I'm using the Cocoa Text Layout System, along with NSTextContainer. As I understand it, that's only possible at the NSView level.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were displaying a PDF, but you're *creating* a PDF from existing views.

Comment: I've made some new suggestions; I think your plan makes sense. You could also try using a layer-backed view and using a transform on that layer. (I'm more used to iOS, where that would be the natural thing to do.)